# Azure set AAD registered application policies

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I have registered an app in Azure AADB2C, and I need to specify that the app requires 2FA enabled before AAD will issue a token, and that the lifetime of the token should be 45 minutes.

Can anyone help? I'm clueless!

This is what I have tried so far

```
az login --allow-no-subscriptions --tenant 46e0e59c-**** // GUID of AAD Tenant
Connect-MgGraph -TenantId 46e0e59c-**** // Same GUID as above

# Create a token lifetime policy
$params = @{
    Definition = @('{"TokenLifetimePolicy":{"Version":1,"AccessTokenLifetime":"PT45M"}}') 
    DisplayName = "WebPolicyScenario"
    IsOrganizationDefault = $false
}
$tokenLifetimePolicyId=(New-MgPolicyTokenLifetimePolicy -BodyParameter $params).Id
```

But I get the following

```
New-MgPolicyTokenLifetimePolicy : Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.
At C:\data\mine\AirSoftwareLtd\ClientData\CommissioningAlliance\CASA\Infrastructure\dev.ps1:9 char:1
+ $tokenLifetimePolicyId=(New-MgPolicyTokenLifetimePolicy -BodyParamete ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: ({ body = Micros...ifetimePolicy }:<>f__AnonymousType0`1) [New-MgPolic
   yTokenLifetimePolicy_Create1], RestException`1
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Authorization_RequestDenied,Microsoft.Graph.PowerShell.Cmdlets.NewMgPolicyTokenLifetimeP
   olicy_Create1
```

**UPDATE**
With help from @rukmini I now have the following...

```
Connect-MgGraph -TenantId 46e0e59c-4d82-4db4-bf08-4a152993cdde -Scopes "Policy.ReadWrite.AuthenticationMethod, Policy.ReadWrite.ApplicationConfiguration, Policy.ReadWrite.TrustFramework"

$params = @{  
Definition = @('{"TokenLifetimePolicy":{"Version":1,"AccessTokenLifetime":"00:45:00"}}')  
DisplayName = "WebPolicyScenario"  
IsOrganizationDefault = $false  
}  
$tokenLifetimePolicyId=(New-MgPolicyTokenLifetimePolicy -BodyParameter $params).Id
```

When I try to append the following script to assign the policy to the app, I get the same "insufficient privileges" error

```
$params = @{
    "@odata.id" = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/policies/tokenLifetimePolicies/$tokenLifetimePolicyId"
}

$applicationObjectId="6e5d07b5-0e86-473a-97e5-6684d0874b99"

New-MgApplicationTokenLifetimePolicyByRef -ApplicationId $applicationObjectId -BodyParameter $params
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got the same error like below:***

[image]

To error usually occurs if the user is not having required permissions to perform the operation.

**To resolve the error**, make sure to assign Global Administrator role and connect to **MgGraph** with `Policy.ReadWrite.TrustFramework` scope.

[image]

To create the Token lifetime Policy, I modified the script like below:

```
Connect-MgGraph -TenantId TenantID -Scopes "Policy.ReadWrite.TrustFramework"

$params = @{  
Definition = @('{"TokenLifetimePolicy":{"Version":1,"AccessTokenLifetime":"00:45:00"}}')  
DisplayName = "WebPolicyScenario"  
IsOrganizationDefault = $false  
}  
$tokenLifetimePolicyId=(New-MgPolicyTokenLifetimePolicy -BodyParameter $params).Id
```

[image]

After assigning Token Lifetime Policy, when **I generated access token the lifetime is 45 mins** like below:

```json
https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id:ClientID
client_secret:ClientSecret
scope:https://graph.microsoft.com/.default
grant_type:client_credentials
```

[image]

***If still the issue persists***, try connecting to MgGraph with `Policy.ReadWrite.AuthenticationMethod` or `Policy.ReadWrite.AuthenticationMethod` or `Policy.ReadWrite.ApplicationConfiguration` permissions.

Comment: Thank you! Your answer helped me to make progress. There is a final piece I am unable to make work which I have included in the question - would you mind seeing if you know the answer to the final part of the problem?

Comment: Try using scope as "Policy.ReadWrite.ApplicationConfiguration" while connecting MgGraph and check.

Answer (score 0):

I used following document commands and could change "AccessTokenLifetime" for specific application as global admin user.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/configure-token-lifetimes#create-a-policy-for-web-sign-in

You need install "Microsoft.Graph.Identity.Governance" before input commands.

```
Install-Module Microsoft.Graph.Identity.Governance
```

And you need to get your application ID by command or Azure AD console.
You could get ID from command or Azure AD "App registrations" pane.

```
Get-MgApplication
```

**Attention, Application ID is NOT Azure AD "Enterprise App" ID.**
If you use "Enterprise App" application-ID or object-ID, you will get "resource not found error" at New-MgApplicationTokenLifetimePolicyByRef command.