# Azure AD expired - CORS issue

Tags: spring-boot, java-8, azure-active-directory, vuejs3

I have implemented Azure AD based login mechanism for our application. I have configured my application in Azure with the `WEB` platform. Below is the flow of requests when I login for the first time.

1. `https://my-service-test2.com/api/signin?post_login_redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fmy-ui-test2.com%2Fhome`
2. `https://my-service-test2.com/oauth2/authorization/azure`
3. `https://login.microsoftonline.com/<>/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=<>&scope=openid%20profile%20offline_access&state=<>&redirect_uri=https://my-service-test2.com/login/oauth2/code/&nonce=<>`
4. `https://my-service-test2.com/login/oauth2/code/?code=<>&state=<>&session_state=<>`
5. `https://my-ui-test2.com/home`

Everything works fine. But the session gets expired in 30mins and I'm seeing a CORS issue

`Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/<>/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=<>&scope=openid%20profile%20offline_access&state=<>&redirect_uri=https://my-service-test2.com/login/oauth2/code/&nonce=<>' (redirected from 'https://my-service-test2.com/api/product/productDetails') from origin 'https://my-ui-test2.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`

Comment: Is your Azure AD access token getting expired and then you are getting CORS error?

Comment: @Rukmini Yes. the token gets expired and the it tries to authenticate again on expiry and seems here getting CORS error. 
I have already set the headers
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *

Comment: Can you decode the access token in https://jwt.ms and paste the screenshot?

Comment: @Rukmini Here are the values that I get from logs..... [Authentication=OAuth2AuthenticationToken]....
 exp=2023-08-25T11:25:35Z, iat=2023-08-25T10:20:35Z

Answer (score 0):

> **Note** that: The CORS error may occur if the access token expires when the application redirects to `login.microsoftonline.com` to authenticate.

**To resolve the error**, you can extend the Access token Lifetime Policy to prevent access token from expiring during a user’s session.

```json
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/policies/tokenLifetimePolicies
Content-type: application/json

{
    "definition": [
        "{\"TokenLifetimePolicy\":{\"Version\":1,\"AccessTokenLifetime\":\"23:59:59\"}}"
    ],
    "displayName": "Contoso token lifetime policy",
    "isOrganizationDefault": true
}
```

[image]

- Based on your requirement, you can set the access token lifetime policy minimum of **5 minutes to maximum of 24 hours**.
- You can also assign the token lifetime policy for a particular application. Refer [**this**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.graph.applications/new-mgapplicationtokenlifetimepolicybyref?view=graph-powershell-1.0).

I used the below **authorize** endpoint:

```json
https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
&client_id=ClientID
&response_type=code
&redirect_uri=https://jwt.ms
&response_mode=query
&scope=api://xxx/.default
&state=12345
```

[image]

I generated the access token via *Postman* by using below parameters and **the access token lifetime is increased to 24 hours** like below:

```json
https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id:ClientID
scope:api://xxx/.default openid
grant_type:authorization_code
redirect_uri:https://jwt.ms
code:code
client_secret:ClientSecret
```

[image]

**References:**

[Understand and solve Azure Active Directory Application Proxy CORS issues - Microsoft Entra](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/app-proxy/application-proxy-understand-cors-issues#option-5-extend-the-lifetime-of-the-access-token)

[Azure set AAD registered application policies - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75988080/azure-set-aad-registered-application-policies) by me