# Azure Entra ID tokens endpoint issues an expired token

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, active-directory

This is a copy of [our question posted at MS community forum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1377508/oauth-tokens-endpoint-issues-expired-token), as it didn't get much traction.

- We have a Web App that supports a Single Sign-On via Azure
- We have a corresponding app registration within the AD
- We are using a hybrid authentication flow, following the OIDC

The flow has been previously tested with several other registrations and works fine for all our tenants, except for this one specific tenant (tried several app registrations from the tenant, all the registrations have the same issue). The tenant didn't customise token lifetime.

The endpoint used to issue a token is: `https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantId}/oauth2/v2.0/token` (Single-tenant app registration)

The flow uses the data from an id token, that needs to be verified first. [A popular NodeJS package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonwebtoken) is used to verify the token. The problem is that the token always fails to be verified. This is due to the lifetime and expiration of the token, which are represented by the `iat` and `exp` properties within the token payload.

For example, a token with a payload such as:

```json
{
...,
"iat": 1695209618,
"nbf": 1695209618,
"exp": 1695209918,
...,
"auth_time": 1695209915,
...}
```

The problem with those values is that this token was requested at `1695209915` , which is almost **5 minutes after** the `iat` . So the first part of the problem is that the endpoint always issues a token which is almost 5 minutes old. The second part of the problem is the fact that by the time the token arrives to the server it's always already expired. So unless you ignore the token expiry, it can never be validated. FYI, the token from the example above was received by `1695209919`, which is exactly after it had expired.

To recap the weird moments:

- A token is always issued as 5 minutes old
- The `iat` is always before the auth_time
- By the time the token arrives, it's already expired
- The token lifetime is only 5 minutes (I read in the Azure docs that the minimum lifetime for an id token is 10 minutes)

We would appreciate directions and suggestions, from more experienced Azure Identity Platform users, about where to look at, to debug and find the cause of the problem.

What we have tried so far:

- Re-registered the application
- Double-checked all endpoints and client credentials
- Inspecting the tokens closely

Comment: Can you set the token lifetime policy as 1 hour and check? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75988080/azure-set-aad-registered-application-policies

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Agreed. Our next step is to compare the app registration manifest with a "working one".
Thanks for the tip about a custom token lifetime. We'll try it. I'll report back about the results.

Comment: Yes Sure let me know if it works. I will post it as an answer

Answer (score 0):

> **Note** that: If the same flow is working for all the tenants but not one tenant then it might a configuration setup error or some policy which is overriding in the tenant.

Hence try creating the **custom token lifetime** by using below query:

```json
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/policies/tokenLifetimePolicies
Content-type: application/json

{
    "definition": [
        "{\"TokenLifetimePolicy\":{\"Version\":1,\"AccessTokenLifetime\":\"8:00:00\"}}"
    ],
    "displayName": "Contoso token lifetime policy",
    "isOrganizationDefault": true
}
```

[image]

For **sample**, I set the token lifetime for 8 hours and generated the **access token** using below parameters:

```json
https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id:ClientID
scope:https://graph.microsoft.com/.default
code:code
redirect_uri:https://jwt.ms
grant_type:authorization_code
client_secret:ClientSecret
```

[image]

The access token is generated with 8 hours of lifetime.

**If still the issue persists**, check the below:

- Make sure no policy is overriding the token lifetime policy.
- Check the manifest of the application is set correctly.
- Check if there is any time sync issue that is **clock skew** where the client clock and the token issuing service clock are not in sync.

**References:**

[Clock skew of 5 minutes  AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js · GitHub](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/issues/512)

[Create tokenLifetimePolicy - Microsoft Graph v1.0 | Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/tokenlifetimepolicy-post-tokenlifetimepolicies?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#request)